# How can I do a soft upgrade from PostGIS 2.1.4 to 2.2.2?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.2

I am running PostGIS on Linux Mint 17.2 using versions in ubuntugis-unstable PPA. I recently updated from `2.1.4+dfsg-3~trusty` to `2.2.2+dfsg-2~trusty0`. Using soft upgrade instructions http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#soft_upgrade_extensions I tried:

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.2.2";
```

However, the result is:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.2": No such file or directory
```

Other info:

```
$ pg_config --libdir
/usr/lib
$ pg_config --pkglibdir
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib
```

Neither location has a `postgis-2.2` folder. Extension control files and upgrade scripts (such as `postgis--2.1.4--2.2.2.sql`) are in `/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension`. Additionally, I have a `/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/contrib/postgis-2.2` folder which has the `postgis_upgrade.sql` file, which is littered with references to `$libdir/postgis-2.2`. Presumably this is the script that gets called by the `ALTER EXTENSION` statement, triggering the "no such" error.

How can I correctly do a soft upgrade? I am trying to avoid doing a dump and reload of the data.

Comment: Is `postgis-2.2.so` in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib`? If you run `ldd` on it, does the system find every dependent library?

Comment: @PaulRamsey No, there is no `postgis-2.2.so` file in that dir.

Comment: Anywhere on the system at all? `find / -name postgis-2.2.so` If not, your package is broken, you can't have postgis without the library file.

Comment: Nowhere on system. I did previously have a working PostGIS 2.1, but there is also no `postgis-2.1.so` in that dir. Would there have been one that was then removed during upgrade? Should I try downgrading?

Comment: Sounds like your `ALTER EXTENSION UPGRADE` failed mid-way, which means thanks to transaction integrity your database probably still thinks it's 2.1. Does your database still work (do spatial things?). If not, then yes, you'll need to try and downgrade your Mint package to 2.1 to get a working .so file back in place.

Comment: @PaulRamsey No database does not work. First time I tried to load a spatial table, I got message that it could not find `$libdir/postgis-2.1`. Then I remembered I had done the apt upgrade and tried `ALTER EXTENSION UPGRADE`.

Comment: I've also confirmed the presence of `postgis-2.1.so` on another installation that was not yet upgraded. Is `*.so` installed by apt or created by `CREATE|ALTER EXTENSION`? I'll try downgrading later tonight and see what happens.